# Let $A$ be a countable set. Prove that $A^{\mathbb N}$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $A$ be a countable set. Prove that $A^{\mathbb N}$ is countable.

Just had trouble proving this. I thought about using a bijection but i wasn't really getting anywhere with that.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Might be a bit tricky given that it's false....

Comment: Even letting $A = \{0,1\}$, $A^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all infinite binary sequences...

Comment: Assuming that we are referring to/using cardinal arithmetic, $\mathbb{N}$ here can be substituted for $\aleph_0$, so that in the case that A is the cardinal 2, your hypothesis is that $2^{\aleph_0}$ (the cardinality of the continuum) is countable. This is elementarily false.

Answer (score 2):

As many already pointed out, this is simply wrong: consider the set $A :=\{0,1\}$. Then by Cantor's theorem, $2^\mathbb{N}$ is *uncountable*.

> **(Cantor's Theorem).** For every set $A$, we have that $$|2^A| > |A|.$$

*Proof.* Since there is an obvious injection $i : A \to 2^A$ given by $$x \mapsto \{x\}$$ it is enough to show that there exists no surjection from $A$ to $2^A$. So let $g: A \to 2^A$ be an arbitrary function and consider $$\Gamma := \{x \in A : x \notin g(x)\} \subseteq A.$$ Thus $\Gamma \in 2^A$. Towards a contradiction, assume that there exists a $y \in A$ such that $g(y) = \Gamma$. Now, if $y \in \Gamma$, then $$y \notin g(y) = \Gamma$$ and if $y \notin \Gamma$, then $y \in \Gamma$ by definition of $\Gamma$, which is absurd. Thus $\Gamma \notin \mathrm{im}(g)$ for any function $g$. $\quad\>\>\>\>\Box$

Comment: Ok I've been hearing that a lot and it does make a lot of sense but how did you prove that 2^N was uncountable?

Comment: @matchesmalone Hope the edit helps.